# searchable plugin not allowed to create directories

Tags: grails, plugins, searchable

I just deployed a grails web application on a linux machine that also acts as a firewall to the network.

we used the apache tomcat web server to run the web-app, but it does seem to have some problems with the searchable plugin. running on my machine, everything seems to work fine but when I tried to deploy it on the firewall server, it gave me a message that it does not have the permissions to create necessary directories.

I'm sorry I can't display the actual error message but basically I believe it does not have permission to create directories and I am not really what do I have to give permission to so the grails application could do its thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the docs ( http://grails.org/plugin/searchable ) - see http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Configuration. If the default location doesn't work for you, run the `install-searchable-config` script and set the `compassConnection` property to one that does.